# How to change Header and footer of a specific webpage while using react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mern

I am a beginner and developing a website for one of my college societies. I have 2 questions here
I can develop a separate blog website but how to integrate it with the existing web app in the "/blog" route and fetch data from it and show it on the home page. I know express and mongoose but I am not sure how to implement this?

I have used react routes for ease in development and repeated header and footer.  but I want to build the front end of the blog website on a different theme, same for a website of event society is going to organize.
I leaving a link to its GitHub repo for reference https://github.com/SME-IIT-ISM

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check **[this blog post](https://reactgo.com/reactrouter-header-footer/)**. It may solve your problem.
I went through the post and the information provided there is much helpful.

1. **Creating a header and footer component**

First, we need to create two new files called header.js, footer.js in our src folder or components folder.

Now inside header.js add your react app navigation links like i have shown in the below code.

- **header.js**

  ```
   import React from "react";
   import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

   function Header() {
     return (
       <nav>
         <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
           Home
         </NavLink>
         <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/users">
           Users
         </NavLink>
         <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/contact">
           Contact
         </NavLink>
       </nav>
     );
   }
   export default Header;
  ```

Next, we need to add a footer related code to footer.js file.

1. **footer.js**

   ```
   import React from "react";
   function Footer() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>This is footer</h1>
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default Footer;
   ```
2. **Adding header and footer**

Now you have successfully created two components, now you have to add a header, footer components to index.js file, so that we can see the both components on every page we navigate.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Users from "./users";
import Contact from "./contact";
import Notfound from "./notfound";
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <hr />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route component={Notfound} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```